# Writing into firestore problems

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When trying to execute a writing function in my app, I receive this error:
[2021-01-24T05:10:45.104Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.2.2): Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
The problem is that I'm trying to write a document inside a collection in firestore, but when executing the function that code is returned in the console.

```
function sendMsg(){
if(!msg==''){
  db.collection('conversations').doc().set({
    userUid1: userAuth.uid,
    userUid2: chatuser.uid,
    msg,
    date: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    viewed: false
  })
}
}
```

Also, I use a useEffect to get these messages from the database which I belive it might be causing this problem but not so sure how to fix it.

```
useEffect(()=>{

db.collection('users')
.where('uid','!=', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
.onSnapshot(querySnapshot=>{
  let users = []
   querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
        users.push(doc.data())

   })
    setUsers(users)
 })

db.collection('conversations')
  .orderBy('date', 'asc') 
  .onSnapshot(querySnapshot=>{
 let conversations = []  

querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>{
    conversations.push(doc.data()) 
  })
  setMsgs(conversations)
})

  }, [])
```

Comment: This error occurred because you are exceeding a limit mentioned in this doc - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas.. Basically, this message will be logged when we get a resource-exhausted error from the backend.

Comment: i actually transfered my entire app into a new react file and the problem was fixed, ofc i created a new app in the firebase too. so might have just been caused because firebase is bugged

Comment: if you wonder whether you reached the limit or not, visit this [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) you can check the usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting this error, I decided to just create a new app on the firebase website and also just creating a new file for my appp. Copy and pasted everything from the old app and I no longer had this issue.